# How I can add undo functionality with SubSonic

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

How I can add undo functionality with SubSonic?

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get many answers with this.  Undo functionality is very costly and complex to implement.  I think Rob toyed around with adding automatic undo functionality in (based on parallel tables with names set by convention), but I don't think that went anywhere.  He's been spending his time on bringing SubSonic into linq-land and T4-ville.

If you're looking for an ORM/data object framework that has undo baked in, you'll probably want to check out [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/).  It is, no surprise, a heavy duty framework which will probably require some heavy lifting to get it into your application.  You'll have to do some of the database work SubSonic does for you, no matter what.